# Set up a home server with mini pc and linux

Tags: linux, drivers, home-server

I want to have a linux (debian/ubuntu) home server, for my work/torrent/files access from my lan and wan.

what I have now is a virtual pc (VBox) running on my desktop (windows), but I want a dedicate machine, I was searching on the web for those mini pc, my idea is to have it next to the my router (no keyboard, no monitor).

until now i have two option in mind:

- asus Eb1505
- intel nuc i3-3217U 4GB, WiFi, SSD 60GB

my question is if somebody set up something like this, there is problems with noise or heat?, drivers? or another hardware model small like those?

Comment: If all you're going to do with it is torrent and file server, you could use something like a Raspberry Pi with a USB hard drive to do the same thing for much cheaper.

Comment: I thought about that, but I read some problems about the SD cards and also I need it for work, I need to store some databases with 1GB average, sql queries test, db dumps and backups.

Comment: HP's Proliant N54L microserver has gained quite a following in this area. It is lower CPU power than the ones you've mentioned, but if what you are looking for is a low power consumption supercharged NAS it is ideal (and probably cheaper). 4 SATA slots and enough CPU power to adequately run XBMC/Plex/Torrent/MySQL etc.

Comment: looks nice, is just I was thinking something smaller and light, 7 kg is too much because I want also to be portable.

Comment: @armandfp If you use the USB Hard drive as the root rather than the SD Card, the Pi is as reliable as any other device for a simple task like this.

Comment: I read that is posible to install a linux on the usb, but also is about the read/write times; how reliable is having this 24/7? are you talking about usb 16/32 GB or usb hard drive 500GB/1TB

Answer (score 1):

I've recently purchased an Intel NUC i5, 8GB RAM, 240GB SSD... amazing little piece of kit, and runs quite quietly, and cool. However, I haven't really put it under any load yet - I've installed Ubuntu 14.04, and installed xen-hypervisor. So far I've only added two guests, one to run Plex Media server, and another provide core services like a puppet master and LDAP.

I'd highly recommend them - they're relatively inexpensive, perfect as a hobbyist machine - but you should be aware that they come as 'bare-bones' kit machines, without RAM / storage / wifi/bluetooth. All components are easy to find though - I purchased all of them on Amazon (in the UK)

Absolutely no problems with drivers, all components picked up and installed... however, I've only used the onboard LAN, not installed a wifi card. I setup LVM on the mSATA disk, and everything has gone super smoothly.